# If f(x+y)=f(x)*f(y) and f is a bijection, show that its inverse satisfies this function equation

Tags: inverse

I'm having trouble with this problem. I'm not even sure how to go about finding the inverse of an equation with both x and y.

Here is the problem:

If $f(x+y)=f(x)*f(y)$ and $f$ is a bijection, show that its inverse satisfies the functional equation:

$f^{-1}(xy)=f^{-1}x+f^{-1}(y)$

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You might see things more clearly if you pretend that $f$ is the exponential function, $f(t)=\exp(t)=e^t$, reals to positive reals. Then in effect you want to show that $\ln(xy)=\ln x+\ln y$, except that you will use $f$ for $\exp$ and $f^{-1}$ for $\ln$.

Comment: That is a very helpful way of thinking about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$f(f^{-1}(x)+f^{-1}(y))=f(f^{-1}(x))f(f^{-1}(y))=xy=f(f^{-1}(xy))$ since $f$ is bijective, $f^{-1}(x)+f^{-1}(y)=f^{-1}(xy)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Take $f^{-1}$ on both sides of the functional equation to find that
$$
f^{-1}(f(x + y)) = f^{-1}(f(x)\cdot f(y))
$$
Note that if $f$ is a bijection, $x$ and $y$ can be written as $f^{-1}(a)$ and $f^{-1}(b)$ for some $a$ and $b$.